# GSAP using splitText on slide not appearing properly

Tags: animation, split, gsap

I want to implement text changing component from [www.papertiger.com](https://www.papertiger.com/), Getting a gap after the third line of text, before it loops. How do I make it loop seamlessly?

Here is my codepen [`link`](https://codepen.io/chetan3460/pen/XWxWKMV?editors=0010)
[image]

```js
const view = document.querySelector("#homepage");
const DOM = {
  homeTickerTitle: view.querySelector(".c-ticker_title"),
  homeTickerTitleChars: view.querySelectorAll(".ticker-line:first-child .char")
};
function Ticker() {
  // Store reference to `this`
  var self = this;

  function splitText(t) {
    return new SplitType(t, {
      type: "words,chars",
      charsClass: "char",
      wordsClass: "word"
    });
  }
  this.init = function() {
    // Split ticker title text
    splitText(".c-ticker_title .t-d1-fluid");

    // Set initial CSS for all ticker lines
    self.lines.forEach(function(line) {
      var chars = line.querySelectorAll(".char");
      gsap.set(chars, {
        yPercent: -100
      });
    });
  };

  // Animate method
  this.animate = function() {
    // Get char elements for each ticker line
    var line1Chars = self.lines[0].querySelectorAll(".char");
    var line2Chars = self.lines[1].querySelectorAll(".char");
    var line3Chars = self.lines[2].querySelectorAll(".char");

    // Create timeline animation
    self.animation = gsap.timeline({
      repeat: -1,
      repeatDelay: 1,
      defaults: {
        duration: 1,
        ease: "expo.inOut"
      }
    });

    // Animate each line in sequence
    self.animation
      .to(line1Chars, {
        yPercent: 100,
        stagger: 0.01
      })
      .to(line2Chars, {
        yPercent: 0,
        stagger: 0.01
      }, "-=1")
      .to(line2Chars, {
        yPercent: 100,
        stagger: 0.01,
        delay: 1
      })
      .to(line3Chars, {
        yPercent: 0,
        stagger: 0.01
      }, "-=1")
      .to(line3Chars, {
        yPercent: 100,
        stagger: 0.01,
        delay: 1
      }, "A")
      .set(line1Chars, {
        yPercent: -100
      }, "A")
      .to(line1Chars, {
        yPercent: 0,
        stagger: 0.01
      }, "-=1");
  };

  // Get DOM elements and initialize ticker
  this.view = document.querySelector("#homepage");
  this.el = this.view.querySelector(".c-ticker");
  this.lines = this.el.querySelectorAll(".ticker-line");
  this.init();
}

// Instantiate Ticker and start animation
var ticker = new Ticker();
ticker.animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://assets.website-files.com/60e4912ee7c15fb303f4c588/css/pt-site-2023.6f47e2f5b.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://webflow-assets.papertigerhq.com/Paper-Tiger-Website/build/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/split-type@0.3.3/umd/index.min.js"></script>

<div id="homepage">
  <div class="c-ticker">
    <div class="c-ticker_side">
      <h2 class="t-micro-1">
        BUILDING BADASS<br />WEBSITES
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="c-ticker_title">
      <h2 class="t-d1-fluid ticker-line">BRAND VISION</h2>
      <h2 class="t-d1-fluid ticker-line">DESIGN CULTURE</h2>
      <h3 class="t-d1-fluid ticker-line">TECHNICAL PROWESS</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="c-ticker_side rt">
      <h2 class="t-micro-1">
        FOR AMBITIOUS<br />BRANDS
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Your question needs to be self-contained. The links are certainly permitted but your question needs to be understandable by someone who is unable or unwilling to click through (and of course, the links will probably eventually stop working, or link to something else than you wanted, and possibly unwelcome). Please [edit] to clarify what your code should do and show enough code that we can see your approach without having to visit the codepen. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].